# Expectation of sum with the signum function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables, $\mathbb{E}X_n=a=\mathrm{const}$.

How to prove that
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(X_{k+1}-X_k)\,\mathrm{sign}(a-X_k)\Big)>0
$$
for sufficiently large $n$  $(n\geq N)\,$?

Thank you very much in advance!

As I see, if $X_k<a$ then one "expects" that $X_{k+1}>X_k$,

and if $X_k>a$ then one "expects" that $X_{k+1}<X_k$

(since $(X_{k+1}-X_k)\,\mathrm{sign}(a-X_k)>0$ is equivalent to $(X_{k+1}-X_k)(a-X_k)>0$).

Comment: Your argument essentially works, although (a) when $X_n$ is almost surely constant you will have equality, and (b) you need $n+1$ values  to  have $n$ differences.  I would use the point that  $\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(X_{k+1}-X_k)\,\mathrm{sign}(a-X_k)\right] = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left[(X_{k+1}-X_k)\,\mathrm{sign}(a-X_k)\right]$ and each expectation on the right hand side is positive (or at least non-negative), for the reason you give